# Triggering when a event does not happens after some seconds using CEP

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

I know how to trigger when an event occurs some time during a time window, like this:

```
select count(*) from MyEvent.win:time(10 sec) having count(*) >= 3
```

But how to trigger when no event occurs during 10 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select * from pattern[every(timer:interval(10) and not MyEvent)]
```

There is a solution patterns page in Esper documentation that has some more information on detecting absences.